# 'GoogleHttpClient.send' ('Future<StreamedResponse> Function(BaseRequest)') isn't a valid override of 'IOClient.send'

Tags: http, flutter, dart, google-api

I can not understand what's the problem here in my code?

```
class GoogleHttpClient extends IOClient {
  Map<String, String> _headers;

  GoogleHttpClient(this._headers) : super();

  @override
  Future<StreamedResponse> send(BaseRequest request) =>
      super.send(request..headers.addAll(_headers));

  @override
  Future<Response> head(Object url, {Map<String, String> headers}) =>
      super.head(url, headers: headers..addAll(_headers));
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go

```
class GoogleHttpClient extends IOClient {
  Map<String, String> _headers;

  GoogleHttpClient(this._headers) : super();

  @override
  Future<IOStreamedResponse> send(BaseRequest request) =>
      super.send(request..headers.addAll(_headers));

  @override
  Future<Response> head(Object url, {Map<String, String> headers}) =>
      super.head(url, headers: headers..addAll(_headers));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class GoogleHttpClient extends IOClient {
  Map<String, String> _headers;

  GoogleHttpClient(this._headers) : super();

  @override
  Future<IOStreamedResponse> send(BaseRequest request) =>
      super.send(request..headers.addAll(_headers));

  @override
  Future<Response> head(Object url, {Map<String, String> headers}) =>
      super.head(url, headers: headers..addAll(_headers));

}
```